# Subtitle Encoding using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, fluent-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I want to read and write subtitle stream

```
ffmpeg -i E:/Video/Waka.mp4 -vf subtitles=E:/Video/Waka.srt out.mp4
```

equivalent code in c or c++ 
and please provide how to add subtitle stream and encoding parameter, what is procedure to read subtitle stream and render at screan

Comment: Asking for code isn't going to help.

Comment: I just want what parameter set for adding subtitle stream?

Comment: Look at this: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtitle Stream encode and while decoding we find data stream so dnt worry just get data with stream index while reading packet.